# How to switch to a particular page using jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a page in which i want to give the users the option to go to a particular page .

The default pagination is there which enables the user to traverse in the range of 5 pages .

But i want to give  an option to switch to any page_number that they  input in an input text field .

I have tried using `t.fnPageChange(page_number)` , but this gives me this  error .

[image]

Comment: can you show an example link so that we can check and let you know

Comment: Sourav Prem   check the answers below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [datatables API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page()), you may want to use `page` instead of `fnPageChange`; if you extracted `page_number` from a textfield, it will probably be a string, and the library is trying to interpret it as an *action* instead of a *number*.

Remember to transform the page into an integer before passing it to `page()`:

```
int_page_number = parseInt(page_number);
t.page(int_page_number);
```

Comment: In my case i had to change it to Number(x) . Then it worked fine